# Unable to access api via Azure website

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services, api, azure

I am using HttpClient to make the request.

Below is the original stack error:

`System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 209.99.17.14:443 at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)Reqes`

The same code works in local dev environment.

Comment: Check the firewall on both ends.

Comment: I am hosting it via Azure websites, I am not sure where to edit any firewall settings. The management portal doesn't have any options.

Comment: Also the API is from a third-party. And the same API call works when I run it locally.

Comment: Who is `209.99.17.14`? That doesn't look like Azure.

Comment: Thats the web service Prodivder which I am trying to access.

Comment: Can you tell more about this service provider? As mentioned by @SLaks, could it be possible that they allow traffic from certain locations (IP addresses) only?

Comment: The provider is ResellerClub. I checked with their support and everything seems ok. I have a hunch the IP address which shows up in Azure websites for our website doesn't really resolve to the real one.

Comment: I think I will have to get a SSL cert for the domain which is mapped to the website. I think once the domain is mapped and SSL configured Azure provides a Virtual IP address. Which I think is the actual IP I need to whitelist.