# MVC Google ouath with Azure website domain issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, oauth

When our website was mywebsite.azurewebsites.net, Google ouath worked fine.

However, now when we added a domain in Azure Portal to map to the website, when the same user logs in using google oauth it doesn't recognise it and asks to register. On register it throws a error saying user already exists.

Not sure what has changed since we added a domain to our website.

Comment: Are you using Azure ACS? if so you need to specify proper relying parties with new domain.

Comment: When you say `On register it throws a error saying user already exists` - does this happen on your website or on Google's site?

Comment: No I am not. I am using the in-built oauth functionality in MVC5.

Comment: @GauravMantri This happens on our site.

Comment: And what's your logic for checking if the user is present in your system? Are you using the token returned by Google by any chance to identify the user?

Comment: @GauravMantri To be honest, I am not doing any checks. I am using the complete vanilla settings MVC5 has to offer.

Comment: Aah. I see. Let me explain what could be wrong in an answer. See if that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you authenticate somebody using Google, among other things you get 2 things back from Google: 1) A user identifier which is some cryptic string and 2) user's email address or name. Now this user identifier is different for each site so if I login using my Google account in site A I get some identifier however if I login using my Google account in site B, I get a different identifier back.

Please check how this identifier is wired into your registration engine. Because you changed the domain name, same user who tries to login would get a different identifier. If the registration engine is checking this first to see if the user is a registered user or not, because the identifier is different, it will indicate that the user is not registered and thus redirect the user to the registration page. Now if the registration engine checks for the user's email (which will be the same in both cases) for duplicate registration, then it will throw the error which you're getting currently.

I may be completely wrong here because I haven't looked at the code. If so, please let me know and I will remove this answer.

**UPDATE**

So I had a chance to play with this and it is indeed the issue with the identifier. I started by creating a simple MVC app in VS 2013 and enabled Google authentication there. I let the application run on its default port. I went to Google, got myself authenticated and got redirected to the application. As expected, it asked me to register which I did.

Then I changed the port on which the application is running (earlier it was running on `50902` and I changed it to run on `50903`). When the application ran, I clicked login and chose Google again. As expected it redirected it me to Google's site and I authenticated myself there. However when I got redirected back to application, it asked me to register again. The registration box was pre filled with my name. When I clicked submit, I got the message `Username already taken` (which is the issue you were facing).

Then I looked into the application database especially `AspNetUserLogins` table and found these two entries:

[image]

Now the 1st entry is when the application ran on port 50902 and the second one is when it ran on 50903. As you can see from the screenshots, Google returned different `ProviderKey`.

and here's the screenshot from `AspNetUsers` table:

[image]

As you can see, I had to change the username for the 2nd entry from `GauravMantri` to `GauravMantri1` as the 1st username was already taken even though both times I logged into Google using same account.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am just wondering if there is a simple setting somewhere in mvc5.

Comment: I haven't looked under the hood properly to check what exactly is happening. Looks like I need to do some homework!

Comment: Updated my answer with some more findings. HTH.

Comment: OMG you are incredible. Thanks for all the effort. Sorry if I am asking too much, but how to fix it?

Comment: Thanks :). Unfortunately I don't think we can do anything here as Google sends different identifiers. Most likely you would need let user register with new accounts and then mess with the database to consolidate both user ids. I hope you have limited set of users who are impacted by this. All the best!

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. You are a star!

Comment: I have an another annoying problem. Please check this when you have a minute: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21235840/unable-to-access-api-via-azure-website

Answer (score 3):

If you update to the latest Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google nuget package (v2.1.0), you will get new overloads for app.UseGoogleAuthentication, which allow you to specify the clientId and clientSecret.  Using the same values for both will ensure that you get consistent providerKey values which will then map to the correct user from multiple endpoints.  I use this so that I can share logins between www.example.com and api.example.com.  For example, *every* Startup.Auth.cs should contain the same fragment:

```
    var googleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = "999999999999-99999999999999999999999999999999999.apps.googleusercontent.com",
            ClientSecret = "XxX-zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz",
            CallbackPath = new PathString("/Account/LoginCallback/"),
        };

        // restrict the retrieved information to just signin information
        googleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions.Scope.Add("openid");

        app.UseGoogleAuthentication(googleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions);
```

I would also recommend consulting this related question regarding the "openid" option: [ASP.Net Identity provider requesting too much info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21956365/asp-net-identity-provider-requesting-too-much-info).

Also, be aware that you have to use console.developers.google.com to configure a single Google clientId and clientSecret to recognize all of your redirect URIs.  That means that every hostname/port combination plus /Account/LoginCallback/ needs to be listed.